# Dynamic SQL into a MYSQL VIEW

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, dynamic-sql

I am trying to take my wordpress user table and usermeta table and create a view with all of my custom fields. I have created this Dynamic SQL query, but because it has "sets" in it, I can not create it into a view. Does anyone have any ideas how to convert this query into a view, or multiple views?

```
    SET group_concat_max_len = 5000;
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(IF(usermeta.meta_key = ''',
      meta_key,
      ''', usermeta.meta_value, NULL)) AS ',
      replace(meta_key, ' ', '')
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM extreme_piklist.xs_usermeta;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT users.ID
                    , users.user_login
                    , users.user_email, ', @sql, ' 
                   FROM extreme_piklist.xs_users users
                   LEFT JOIN extreme_piklist.xs_usermeta AS usermeta 
                    ON users.ID = usermeta.user_id
                   GROUP BY users.id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```